How big can a sea turtle get?
So, I'm working on a bestiary and I want to fill the oceans of my world with big greatures, but keeping plausibility by respecting the square cube law, the ecology niches the beasts might occupy, etc.
So, I want one of them to be a gigantic sea turtle that inhabits the tropical waters of a big ocean, but I don't know how big can I make it without breaking readers immersion.
Ideally it would be around 20m (or 65 ft.), but I see that the biggest example in our known biological history is the Archelon species with a respectable 4'6m (or 15 ft.) according to Wikipedia, but not quite enough for me! I want it to be confused by sailors with a small island or a crag.
As for the diet, I was thinking about making it to be a generalist eater, thriving on algae, plankton, and other smaller creatures whenever the occasion arises, making it a sort of an opportunistic predator, but I'm willing to change that in order to maximize its potential size.
Now, my questions are as follow:

How big can I make my sea turtles get? Could it get as big as a blue whale? What would it need to eat in order to get to that size? Could it still efficiently swim in tropical oceanic waters?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Remember our [help]: only 1 question per post.

the major limit on sea turtles is they have to haul their butt out of the ocean to lay eggs, the second is feeding themselves. Make them ovoviviperous filter feeders and you can get whale sized. Or make them eat huge quantities of jelly fish.

We've had a LOT of "how big can X get? questions on this site. They all have fundamentally the same answers. Your knee-jerk reaction might be to discredit my choice of which one you've duplicated, but the reality is that it can max out at the aquatic limit by choosing to no longer come onto land. If you require it to come onto land, this becomes a duplicate of the "how big can a chicken get?" question.

@JBH I tried to find the answer on my own, but I wasn't very good at it, I am so sorry. I assumed the question might come as generic and the question you've linked was, indeed, useful. Thank you very much for the resources and the patience!

@John Thank you too, the idea of making them ovoviviperous is essential to make them stay in the damn water. I'll close the answer.
